# What is alternative to Timer control in C#. NET

Tags: c#

i am using the Timer control and i call lots of functions (ie. 20-30 Sub in Timer1_Tick event )
may be due to performing these multiple operations in interval of 500 milliseconds may applications     not Responding after 2-3 minute..

so there is any alternative for using the timer control...

please suggest me...

if i use multithreading then it is not possible to update values/properties of other Controls. it gives an error

Comment: I believe this is because some issues in the implementation, Timer itself not a problem. So just share code you're using for timer and let's see what is going on

Comment: I'll put a buck on the Tick event handler subscribing the event again.

Answer (score 2):

You can `BackgroundWorker` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)) with following extension to your job

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired) control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(action), null);
        else action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

and then to change anything on UI (UI thread), you can do

```
btnGo.Invoke(() => { btnGo.Text = "Done"; });
prgBar.Invoke(() => { prgBar.PerformStep(); });
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-threading, but if you want to modify a control owned by UI thread, you need to do it using `Control.Invoke` (sync) or `Control.BeginInvoke` (async) in order to get synchronized with UI thread and work with your whole controls.

- Control.Invoke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx
- Control.BeginInvoke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx